# MYSQL CASE statement (if /else)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a CASE statement like below:

```
UPDATE table SET
COL1 = CASE WHEN COL1 = '0' then 'something' else COL1 end,
COL2 = CASE WHEN COL2 = '0' then 'something' else COL2 end,
COL3 = CASE WHEN COL3 = '0' then 'something' else COL3 end
WHERE ID = '$id_example'
```

But I only want the first CASE that is "TRUE" to execute.

EDIT:

```
UPDATE utskick SET
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION f()
BEGIN
    CASE 
       WHEN datum_1 = '0000-00-00' THEN datum_1 = '2020-01-01' ELSE datum_1//
       WHEN datum_2 = '0000-00-00' THEN datum_2 = '2020-01-01' ELSE datum_2//
       WHEN datum_3 = '0000-00-00' THEN datum_3 = '2020-01-01' ELSE datum_3//
    END CASE //
END //
DELIMITER;
CALL f()
WHERE kund_id = '14'
```

EDIT 2:

```
UPDATE table SET
CASE 
    date_1 WHEN date_1 = '0000-00-00' THEN '2020-01-01'
    ELSE
        CASE date_2 WHEN date_2 = '0000-00-00' THEN '2020-01-01'
        ELSE
           CASE date_3 WHEN date_3 = '0000-00-00' THEN '2020-01-01'
        END
    END
END
WHERE id = 23
```

And i'm getting this error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE datum_1 WHEN datum_1 = '0000-00-00' THEN '2020-01-01' ELSE' at line 2

Comment: Say this in the when expression: WHEN (COL2 = '0' AND NOT (COL1 = '0')) etc.

Comment: No doesn't work. If both COL2 and COL3 is empty both gets the new value. Id COL2 is empty I want the query to stop there and do not add a value to COL3.

Comment: thats the etc.: WHEN (COL3 = '0' AND NOT (COL1 = '0' OR COL2 = '0'))

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. Both COL2 and COL3 gets a new value when they are both empty.

Comment: Hm, but if COL1 is iempty it works? Try to change sequence, put the col3-Test first

Comment: @Turo Thank you so much for your help!! Changing the sequence worked!! Please set this as an answer so that I can accept your answer!! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
WHEN (COL3 = '0' AND NOT (COL1 = '0' OR COL2 = '0')) ...
WHEN (COL2 = '0' AND NOT (COL1 = '0')) ...
WHEN COL1 = '0' ...
```

so only the wanted when is true

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the CASE statement you should put it in a function.  Something like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION doSomething(col varchar(3))
BEGIN
    CASE 
       WHEN col = 'col1' THEN dothis //
       WHEN col = 'col2' THEN dothat //
       WHEN col = 'col3' THEN someotherthing //
    END CASE //
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

call the function like:

```
CALL doSomething(@parameter);
```

There's more info info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

Comment: No, can't get this to work. Probably because i'm doing something wrong... See my question code edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested CASE statement as follows:

```
CASE COL1 WHEN '0' THEN 'something1'
ELSE
    CASE COL2 WHEN '0' THEN 'something2'
    ELSE
       CASE WHEN COL3 = '0' THEN 'something3'
       END
    END
END
```

[SqlFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6affa/6)

Comment: It looks right, but sadly I get a bunch of errors when running the query. I can run this statment in a SELECT query but not a UPDATE query.